# Multiply XML tag value if it matches the value of another tag in the same XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

I've been reading about how to multiply an XML tag value if it matches the value of another tag in the same XML, I give you an example:

I have an XML with this values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 1</name>
    <brand>BRAND 1</brand>
    <currency>CURRENCY 1</currency>
    <price>10</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 2</name>
    <brand>BRAND 2</brand>
    <currency>CURRENCY 1</currency>
    <price>5</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 3</name>
    <brand>BRAND 3</brand>
    <currency>CURRENCY 2</currency>
    <price>1</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 4</name>
    <brand>BRAND 4</brand>
    <currency>CURRENCY 2</currency>
    <price>2</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 5</name>
    <brand>BRAND 5</brand>
    <currency>CURRENCY 2</currency>
    <price>5</price>
  </item>
</products>
```

And I need to multiply the values by 10 from the `<price>` tag if they match CURRENCY 2 in the `<currency>` tag leaving a result similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 1</name>
    <brand>BRAND 1</brand>
    <currency>CURRENCY 1</currency>
    <price>10</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 2</name>
    <brand>BRAND 2</brand>
    <currency>CURRENCY 1</currency>
    <price>5</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 3</name>
    <brand>BRAND 3</brand>
    <currency>CURRENCY 2</currency>
    <price>10</price><!--- Have been multiplied by 10 because matched "CURRENCY 2" on the "<currecy>" tag -->
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 4</name>
    <brand>BRAND 4</brand>
    <currency>CURRENCY 2</currency>
    <price>20</price><!--- Have been multiplied by 10... -->
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>PRODUCT 5</name>
    <brand>BRAND 5</brand>
    <currency>CURRENCY 2</currency>
    <price>50</price><!--- Have been multiplied by 10... -->
  </item>
</products>
```

I wrote this code but it does not work and I'm not pretty sure why, any help will be very appreciated.

```
<?php
$sXML = simplexml_load_file('file.xml', null, LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
$currency = $sXML->xpath("//item[currency='CURRENCY 2']");
foreach ( $currency as $value )    {
    $value = $value * 10;
}
unset($value);

$domDocument = dom_import_simplexml($sXML)->ownerDocument;
$domDocument->formatOutput = true;
echo $domDocument->save('new.xml');
?>
```

Comment: You're very nearly there.  Your `$value` variable represents each of the matching `<item>` elements; so you want to be doing `$value->price = $value->price * 10` to manipulate each `<price>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to salathe the magic happens using this sintax `$value->price = $value->price * 10`

```
<?php
$sXML = simplexml_load_file('file.xml', null, LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
$currency = $sXML->xpath("//item[currency='CURRENCY 2']");
foreach ( $currency as $value )    {
    $value->price = $value->price * 10;
}
unset($value);

$domDocument = dom_import_simplexml($sXML)->ownerDocument;
$domDocument->formatOutput = true;
echo $domDocument->save('new.xml');
?>
```